# AGM Map with *ngIf

Tags: angular, agm-map

I'm trying to show a marker label but only on a certain zoom level or greater but it isn't allowing me to use `*ngIf`.

```
<div *ngIf="[zoom]=>15"        
[label]="{color: 'yellow', text: point.ID, fontSize: '4'}" 
</div>
```

How do I show a marker or its label on a certain zoom level in Angular Agm Map?

Component.html

```
<body>

    <div class="map-body">    
        <agm-map class="ngmap" style="text-shadow: 0px 0px 6.2px grey;" 
        [latitude]="30" [longitude]="-79" [styles]="mapStyle" 
        [zoom]="13" [streetViewControl]="false" (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)">            

            <agm-marker         
                *ngFor="let point of points"                
                [latitude]="point.latitude"
                [longitude]="point.longitude" 
                *ngIf="zoom=>15" [label]="{color: 'yellow', text: point.ID, fontSize: '4'}" 
                else [label]=""
                [openInfoWindow]="true"
                (mouseOver)="infoWindow.open();"
                (mouseOut)="infoWindow.close();"
                [iconUrl]="{url:'.././assets/images/icons8-50.png',
                    scaledSize: {height: 20, width: 20}
                    }"                
                >
            <agm-info-window
                [disableAutoPan]="true" #infoWindow>{{point.test}}: <br>{{point.Name}}
            </agm-info-window>                
            </agm-marker
            >            
        </agm-map>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: <div *ngIf="zoom=>15"        
[label]="{color: 'yellow', text: point.ID, fontSize: '4'}" 
</div> If zoom is a variable on the component

Comment: `*ngIf="zoom=>15"` will do.

Comment: Just adding `*ngIf="zoom=>15"` caused the map to not show and the `<div>` tags show up flagged in red and caused an error.

Comment: Can you add your component code so we can see the variables we are working with please.

Comment: @ajrthegreat I've added the component code

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind to properties (i.e. `[label]=""`) inside `*ngIf`.

Instead, get rid of `*ngIf` at the template and bind `[label]` to a method that returns the correct object.

Example:

component.html:

```
<agm-marker *ngFor="let point of points" [latitude]="point.latitude" [longitude]="point.longitude"
  [label]="getMarker(point)" [openInfoWindow]="true" (mouseOver)="infoWindow.open();" (mouseOut)="infoWindow.close();"
  [iconUrl]="{url:'.././assets/images/icons8-50.png', scaledSize: { height: 20, width: 20 }>
```

and on component.ts

```
@Component({ ... })
export class Component {
  getMarker(point: any): any {
    const marker = { color: 'yellow', text: point.ID, fontSize: '4' };
    return (this.zoom >= 15) ? marker : {};
  }
}
```

Comment: It's telling me can't find name for `point.ID` or `MarkerType`. What primitive type do I use to name `MarkerType`. I did zoom as `zoom: Number`.

Comment: did it help @lifespunchingbag